# Bootstrap accordion target links stay active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So what I'm trying to accomplish is I'm building a website using Wordpress. I have a menu and one of the items is "Products" under products I have 4 items, electronics, cars, house supplies, and other. For this example I'm focusing on electronics. So under electronics i have another submenu. So this is the 3rd level, which looks like the code below.

```
<li class="dropdown menu-products"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="http://mywebsite/products/">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu-electronics"><a href="http://mywebsites/product_type/electronics/">Electronics</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-tv"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse414">Tvs</a></li>
        <li class="menu-phones"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse416">Phone</a></li>
        <li class="menu-games"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse418">Games</a></li>
        <li class="menu-other"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse420">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now when I click on any of the links on the 3rd level it will take you to the parent page and open up an accordion for that id. So I set that up and it works. However the problem I'm having is since all of these items example (tv, phones, games, others) are technically on the same page. When I click on one of the links, and i go back to the menu, all the links in the 3rd level are active. So if I were to click on a different item, the url changes but the page doesn't refresh nor does the new target accordion open. Here is what I have so far for this area. I'm assuming I have to add something to this script to check every time a link is clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
        $("#" + anchor).collapse('show');
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Tried to set up a JSfiddle to show this but failed at it.

Comment: I guess you don't need to add a new script. I think you have found an error in your actual script instead. Can you publish a link to your site?

Comment: It's on my local server. Basically, when i click on a link all the links that have targets on that page are active. I just want the anchor that i selected to have the active state

Comment: Try to publish your jvascript and full menu's HTML.